# How to check if the postID is in an array?

Tags: array

In Wordpress, I am trying to check through an if else statement if the post is of a certain ID as follows:

```
<?php if ($post->ID == array(224,222,583,645,203,11,639,228,226,230,634,615,625,214,220,194)) : ?>
    ...do something...
<?php else : ?>
    ...do nothing...
<?php endif; ?>
```

This isn't working. Can you please help in knowing how to use the check the post ID in arrays?

Comment: See [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: Did this but didn;t work
    $post = $wp_query->post;
      if (in_array($post->ID,array(224,222,583,645,203,11,639,228,226,230,634,615,625,214,220,194))) : ?>

Comment: This is essentially off-topic and will likely be closed, but I quickly posted the in_array() solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sally highlights, you can use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like this (untested):

```
// target ids
$ids = array(123, 321, 213);

if (!empty($post->ID) && is_numeric($post->ID) && in_array((int)$post->ID, $ids)) {
   // do jazz
} else {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works like a charm.